# Validate checkbox in jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a PHP form where atleast one checkbox be selected before submitting the form. If submit is clicked without selecting atleast one checkbox, it
needs an alert. Could anyone suggest me doing this in Jquery1.10.2. I tried my best in jquery, its working for me.

```
<script>
function onSubmit() 
{ 
  var fields = $(".chk_boxes1").serializeArray(); 
  if (fields.length == 0) 
  { 
    alert('nothing selected'); 
    // cancel submit
    return false;
  }   
}
// register event on form, not submit button
$('#subscribeForm').submit(onSubmit)
</script>


<?php
echo '<form action="" method="post" id="subscribeForm">               
       <table>
         <tr>                                              
            <th>ROLE</th>
            <th>DESCRIPTION</th>    
            <th>PERMISSIONS<br><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes"></th>  
         </tr>

         <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="role_name" required></td>
            <td><input type="text" value="" name="role_desc" required></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="0">My Account<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="1">Edit Account<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="2">Change password<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="3">List of users<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="4">Define roles<br>
                <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="5">Assign roles<br>
         </td></tr></table>
         <div><input type="submit" name="new_role" value="create newrole"></div>
      </form>';
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with something like this:

```
$("#new_role").on("click",function(){
    if($( "input:checked" ).length == 0)
        alert("You should check something");
    else
        $("#subscribeForm").submit();
});
```

See [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/lparcerisa/kayaso52/)

Comment: After I submit, it gives me an alert but again the page starts refreshing. I want to stay on where I was before.

Comment: Have you changed the input type submit to input type button? (in the fiddle is done this way). You should also set the ID for this element.

Comment: To let you know...I want to submit the data to database, I think we can't use button here

Answer (score 0):

Firstly call the funciton in your form using `onsubmit` event -

```
<form action="" method="post" id="subscribeForm" onsubmit="return onSubmit();">
```

Here is your function to validate the checkboxes

```
function onSubmit() {
    if ($(".chk_boxes1:checked").length < 1) {
        alert("Please select at least one checkbox.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using :checked pseudo element

```
if($('chk_boxes1:checked').length == 0)
{
    alert('At least one checkbox has to be selected')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code : you can change input `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` and call `onSubmit()` function on `onclick` of button. And inside function check if atleast one checkbox is checked using length of checked checkboxes, if condition true then submit form otherwise show alert.

```
    <script>
    function onSubmit() 
    { 
      var checkedCheckbox = $(".chk_boxes1:checked").length; 
      //if no checkbox selected then show alert
      if (checkedCheckbox == 0) 
      { 
        alert('nothing selected'); 
        // cancel submit
        return false;
      }   
      else
     {
        // submit form
         $('#subscribeForm').submit();
      }

    }

    </script>


    <?php
    echo '<form action="" method="post" id="subscribeForm">               
           <table>
             <tr>                                              
                <th>ROLE</th>
                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>    
                <th>PERMISSIONS<br><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes"></th>  
             </tr>

             <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="role_name" required></td>
                <td><input type="text" value="" name="role_desc" required></td>
                <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="0">My Account<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="1">Edit Account<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="2">Change password<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="3">List of users<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="4">Define roles<br>
                    <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="5">Assign roles<br>
             </td></tr></table>
             <div><input type="button" name="new_role" value="create newrole" onclick="onSubmit()"></div>
          </form>';

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Working Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var atLeastOneIsChecked = false;
            function validateForm() {
                $('input:checkbox').each(function () {
                    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                      atLeastOneIsChecked = true;
                    }
                });
                if (!atLeastOneIsChecked) {
                    alert("please tick any of the check boxes");
                }
                else{
                    alert("Success");
                    //submit form
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" id="subscribeForm" onsubmit="return validateForm();">               
            <table>
                <tr>                                              
                   <th>ROLE</th>
                   <th>DESCRIPTION</th>    
                   <th>PERMISSIONS<br><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes"></th>  
                </tr>
                <tr>
                   <td><input type="text" name="role_name" required></td>
                   <td><input type="text" value="" name="role_desc" required></td>
                   <td><input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="0">My Account<br>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="1">Edit Account<br>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="2">Change password<br>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="3">List of users<br>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="4">Define roles<br>
                       <input type="checkbox" class="chk_boxes1" name="perm[]" value="5">Assign roles<br>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <div><input type="submit" name="new_role" value="create newrole"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I executing the code, it shows always 'success'. A wrong code

Comment: @Saranya 
It works for me. It shows success alert only if you select atleast one checkbox. Otherwise,if you dont select one, it will show error alert.  Please try the code again.